# postgresql pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold decreasing

Tags: postgresql, pg-trgm

SET pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold TO 0.2; 
lowers the threshold for current session
but does not do it for database. I need to lower the threshold for supporting spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html) says, there are two options to change the value globally (for the whole database cluster):

1. Add the parameter to `postgresql.conf` and run `pg_ctl reload`.
2. Run `ALTER SYSTEM SET pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold = 0.2;` and `SELECT pg_reload_conf();`.

If you want to change it for a specific database, you can use

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold = 0.2;
```

The new setting will then be effective for all new connections.

Comment: does this make it system specific or database specific ?

Comment: I added some clarification.